# After my script crashes, I can't run any more scripts, RP 3 Model B+

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, crash

I am running a script that is probably crashing. When I run it, nothing seems to happen, so I hit Ctrl + Z to halt the program. But then I can't run any other script on the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+. Nothing happens, just a blinking cursor... when I reboot, I can run scripts again. Why is this?

This is the script that is crashing everything. It crashed when I tried to add the time element... it worked before that. I understand I've probably cause the program to crash, but why does that stop me running any other script after I have halted it?

```py
import grovepi
import time

# Connect the Grove Ultrasonic Ranger to digital port D4
# SIG,NC,VCC,GND
ultrasonic_ranger = 4

while True:
    try:
        # Read distance value from Ultrasonic
        print(grovepi.ultrasonicRead(ultrasonic_ranger))
        time.sleep(1)
    except TypeError:
        print ("Error")
    except IOError:
        print ("Error")
```

**Update** from comment:
I am using VNC viewer and starting the script using the cmd line on the pi. If I hit Ctrl C, I just see the letter ^C on the command line, nothing else happens. When I hit Ctrl Z it halts the program. I will try using Ctrl C first and then Ctrl Z and see if that helps.

Comment: What operating system, what version do you use? Do you sit on a console or on a GUI? What happens if you hit `Ctrl + C` instead of `Crl + Z` on a console?

Comment: Os = Raspian stretch, I am using VNC viewer and starting the script using the cmd line on the pi. If I hit Ctrl C, I just see the letter ^C on the command line, nothing else happens. When I hit Ctrl Z it halts the program. I will try using Ctrl C first and then Ctrl Z and see if that helps.

Comment: just ^z and kill %1

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your terminal emulator. Are you running something like `lxterm` in a desktop session via VNC? Try connecting via SSH for a change.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that `Ctrl + Z` **DOES NOT** *halt the program* - it just stops it from executing.

You should use `Ctrl + c` to kill the task, but you should actually fix the program and include some tests rather than letting an unresponsive task block execution.

Comment: Maybe there is also a problem that VNC (additional later info) isn't transparent for control codes (`Ctrl + Z`, `Ctrl + C`). Do you know?

Comment: @Ingo Possibly there is, who knows what the OP is using? The question seems to be a moving target with significant missing information.